# Is there a way to store int in ObjectID?

Tags: mysql, mongodb, auto-increment, objectid

I'm trying to migrate MySQL user ids to MongoDB. user ids are incremental values like 1,2,3,4...

Is there a way to store int in `ObjectID`?

Comment: If you already have a unique ID value for the documents you are migrating, you can provide this for [the `_id` field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field) instead of using the default generated ObjectID. The `_id` field can include values of any BSON data type other than an array. How are you migrating your documents? Are you getting any specific error or is this a more general question?

Comment: @Stennie IDs are unique, but I'd love to convert them into an ObjectId to make it consistent and take advantage of ObjectId functions & performance

Answer (score 0):

If you don't specify `_id` field when inserting a document in MongoDB, the database internally generates ObjectID and stores the document. In your case, the _id column will be populated with automatically generated ObjectID.

If you want to convert `1, 2, 3, 4` as ObjectID, No you cannot. Because ObjectID should be in `12` bytes .

[The _id Field](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/core/document/#the-id-field)

Comment: I specifically meant to store int inside of random part of ObjectID.

Comment: How are you migrating your MySQL data to MongoDB? I mean are you writing any code (For example Java) to migrate the code. The native mongodb drivers allow you generate objectId using counter.  http://mongodb.github.io/mongo-java-driver/3.10/javadoc/index.html?org/bson/types/ObjectId.html

Comment: I use Python in order to implement a migration script for MySQL to MongoDB

Comment: As per the pymongo driver documentation, There is no out of box method to genarate object id using external counter. https://api.mongodb.com/python/current/api/bson/objectid.html?highlight=objectid#module-bson.objectid . you should write your custom logic to generate ObjectID using external counter. Since it involves programming, it is better to ask your question in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/mongodb website.